# Parallel proof in geometry

Tags: geometry

From $A$, perpendiculars $AX$,$AY$ are drawn to the bisectors of the exterior angles of $B$ and $C$ of triangle $ABC$. Prove that $XY$ is parallel to $BC$

I tried to solve this using angle chasing, and ended up with angle $XAB$ equal to half of angle $B$. But, I could not proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend $AX$ and $AY$ to cut the line $BC$ at points $X',Y'$, respecitvely. Now note that the triangle $AXB$ and $XX'B$ are congruent and this implies that $X$ is the midpoint of $AX'$. Similalry $Y$ is the midpoint of $AY'$. Therefore $XY$ is the midline in the triangle $AX'Y'$, so $XY \parallel X'Y'$, which is infact $BC$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $M$ the middle of $AB$ and $N$ the middle of $AC$. Prove that $X, M, N, Y$ are collinear, simple by calculating angles.